# Phonegap CLI splashscreen not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap

It's been asked several times but I have tried all provided solutions and I still can't make it work.

It's driving me nuts also because each try takes me 5 minutes (uninstall app, build it, download it, accept it, install it, launch it and cry ...)

I have a phonegap project built with https://build.phonegap.com

Here's my `config.xml`, icons seem to work decently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id          = "fr.gouv.beta.passculture-staging"
    version     = "1.0.0" >

  <name>My App</name>

  <description>My description</description>

  <author href="https://example.com" email="email@example.com">
    Me
  </author>

  <access origin="*" />

  <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
    <application android:debuggable="true" />
  </gap:config-file>

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="https://github.com/Addarkar/cordova-plugin-cookie-manager.git#51672c23204e1041fca651611aac6bc65a0759e3" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~4.0.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.3" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.4.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1" />

  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.0.0" />
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />

  <icon src="icon/ic_launcher_google_play.png" />

  <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
  <icon src="icon/app-icon-iphone.png" platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
  <icon src="icon/app-icon-iphone@2x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
  <!-- iPhone 6 / 6+ -->
  <icon src="icon/app-icon-iphone@3x.png" platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />

  <!-- iPad -->
  <icon src="icon/app-icon-ipad.png" platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
  <icon src="icon/app-icon-ipad@2x.png" platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />

  <!-- Settings Icon -->
  <icon src="icon/app-icon-setting.png" platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
  <icon src="icon/app-icon-setting@2x.png" platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
  <icon src="icon/app-icon-setting@3x.png" platform="ios" width="87" height="87" />

  <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
  <icon src="icon/app-icon-spotlight.png" platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
  <icon src="icon/app-icon-spotlight@2x.png" platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
  <icon src="icon/app-icon-spotlight@3x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />

  <icon src="icon/ic_launcher_google_play.png" platform="android" qualifier="ldpi" />
  <icon src="icon/ic_launcher_mdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="mdpi" />
  <icon src="icon/ic_launcher_hdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="hdpi" />
  <icon src="icon/ic_launcher_xhdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="xhdpi" />
  <icon src="icon/ic_launcher_xxhdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="xxhdpi" />
  <icon src="icon/ic_launcher_xxxhdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="xxxhdpi" />

  <!-- NOT WORKING :( -->
  <splash src="splash.png" />

  <splash platform="android" qualifier="ldpi" src="splash.png" />
  <splash platform="android" qualifier="mdpi" src="splash.png" />
  <splash platform="android" qualifier="hdpi" src="splash.png" />
  <splash platform="android" qualifier="xhdpi" src="splash.png" />

  <!-- iPhone and iPod touch -->
  <splash src="Default.png" platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
  <splash src="Default@2x.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />

  <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
  <splash src="Default-568h@2x.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

  <!-- iPhone 6 -->
  <splash src="Default-667h@2x.png" platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
  <splash src="Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png" platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
  <splash src="Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png" platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />

  <!-- iPad -->
  <splash src="Default-Portrait.png" platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
  <splash src="Default-Landscape.png" platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

  <!-- Retina iPad -->
  <splash src="Default-Portrait@2x.png" platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
  <splash src="Default-Landscape@2x.png" platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />

  <!-- Android -->
  <splash src="ldpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="ldpi" />
  <splash src="mdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="mdpi" />
  <splash src="hdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="hdpi" />
  <splash src="xhdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="xhdpi" />
  <splash src="fr-xhdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="fr-xhdpi" />
  <splash src="portrait-xxhdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="port-xxhdpi" />
  <splash src="landscape-xxhdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="land-xxhdpi" />
  <splash src="xxxhdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="xxxhdpi" />

</widget>
```

So, `splash.png` is present at root of the app. I have set plugin `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1" />`, I tried with the `<gap:splash>` tag-names, but read that those where not useful anymore.

So I'm dry of tries...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last try worked. Here's what I changed in `config.xml`. Don't want to know which line fixed it exactly

```
  <!-- instead of spec="~4.0.1" -->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git" />

  <!-- instead of value="splash" -->
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
```